# SQL to_char rounding '9999.99'

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello I was wondering if somebody could explain to me what to_char(number, '999.99') and how when the 9 changes to 0 it affects the output of the number.

for instance if i had the number 123.75 or 123.44 what would happened if it was
'999.90'
'990.00'
'999.99'

just trying to understand what the 9 and 0 mean in the context

Answer (score 2):

It is explained in *any* Oracle database version's documentation for the `TO_CHAR` function, under the [Format models](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm) section.

- 0: returns leading / trailing zeros
- 9:

  - Returns value with the specified number of digits with a leading space if positive or with a leading minus if negative.
  - Leading zeros are blank, except for a zero value, which returns a zero for the integer part of the fixed-point number.

For example:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 123.70 from dual union all
  3     select  10.07 from dual
  4    )
  5  select col,
  6         to_char(col, '999.90') val_1,
  7         to_char(col, '990.00') val_2,
  8         to_char(col, '999.99') val_3
  9  from test;

       COL VAL_1   VAL_2   VAL_3
---------- ------- ------- -------
     123,7  123.70  123.70  123.70
     10,07   10.07   10.07   10.07

SQL>
```

---

Leading zeros:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 123.70 from dual union all
  3     select  10.07 from dual
  4    )
  5  select col,
  6         to_char(col, '0999.90') val_1,
  7         to_char(col, '0990.00') val_2,
  8         to_char(col, '0999.99') val_3
  9  from test;

       COL VAL_1    VAL_2    VAL_3
---------- -------- -------- --------
     123,7  0123.70  0123.70  0123.70
     10,07  0010.07  0010.07  0010.07
            --       --       --         --> these are leading zeros
SQL>
```

Comment: what does leading zeros actually mean sorry ///

Comment: The ones that are displayed at the beginning of the string. I added such an example; have a look.

Comment: thank you ! this is so much easier to understand